# How to change directory icon/color of specific folder in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Exist any way to change the icon or the color of specific folder based in your name?

**Example, to this:**

[image]

**For this:**

[image]

```
{
    "directory": "bot",
    "color: "red"
}
```

Thank you very much =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently possible in Sublime. There is no configurable API to allow any modification to how the side bar is visualized.

While it is possible to [modify your theme](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html#elements-side_bar) to change the icons used for folders, files, etc, there is no mechanism by which you could do that based on the name of the folder in question.

You can [vote for this feature on the Sublime Text issue tracker](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/3586).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @odaNurd =)